# Having issues with copyrighted permissions

Tags: copyright

I would like to be able to sell copyrighted t-shirt designs in my business but I would like to know what I need to do to be able to do this?

Comment: Are these your copyrighted files you want to sell or are you seeking to sell the copyrighted work of others? This question is really unclear.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search brought up this step-by-step list of how to obtain copyright permissions:

[The Basics of Getting Permission](http://fairuse.stanford.edu/overview/introduction/getting-permission/)

1. Determine if permission is needed.
2. Identify the owner.
3. Identify the rights needed.
4. Contact the owner and negotiate whether payment is required.
5. Get your permission agreement in writing.